# Scilab/Xcos: handling strings in Xcos & toolbox function in Xcos

Tags: string, simulation, serial-communication, scilab, xcos

I want to create a simulation in Xcos (part of Scilab) representing the real Arduino Uno system. That means changing its input values during the simulation based on output. The problem is that I need to find the way how to handle strings as input and output. How is this possible?

The solution that comes to my mind is to somehow use Atoms [Serial Communication Toolbox](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/serial/0.4.1) functions like `writeserial()` and `readserial()` in my Xcos scheme. But I do not have any idea if this is even possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use those functions in my Xcos scheme by putting them into Scilab function block (scifunc_block_m) and then parsing them to get the correct output. And it seems that for handling strings in Xcos for input/output it is possible to convert string to `ascii()` and work with that.